# PowerBI_logic operation of variables

Tags: variables, powerbi, logical-operators

I have a data frame "test", as the following:

```
ID  city  quality  year
1   NY    special  2020
2   NY    special  2020
3   NY    special  2020
4   NY    special  2020
5   NY    normal   2020
6   PA    special  2020
1   NY    special  2019
2   NY    special  2019
3   NY    normal   2019
4   BJ    normal   2019
5   BJ    normal   2019
6   PA    normal   2019
```

I would like to give each ID a value: if an ID is new "special" in "NY" at "2020", then the value is 1, otherwise 0. So these two IDs are given 1: 3, 4; all others are give 0.

I start with the following in PowerBI:

```
NY_new special_2020 = 
VAR
  NY_special_2020 = FILTER('test', 'test'[year] = "2020" && 'test'[city]= "NY" && test[quality] = "special")

VAR
  NY_special_2019 = FILTER('test', 'test'[year] = "2019" && 'test'[city]= "NY" && test[quality] = "special")
```

My question is how shall I combine the two variables to keep only those in NY_special_2020, but not in NY_special_2019?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I expect: the two IDs, 3 & 4 are given the value of 1; all others are given the value of 0. Essentially, I would like to take those in NY_special_2020, remove the IDs in NY_special_2019. Thank you!

Comment: Why 3 and 4 as 1 and 2 also holding the same value as 3 and 4? what is your logic for selecting 3 and 4?

Comment: because 3 and 4 appears as new "special" in "NY" in 2020. 1 and 2 are already "special" in "NY" in 2019, so they are not new "special". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this below measure to achieve your required output-

```
new_special = 

var current_id = MIN(your_table_name[ID])
var current_year = MIN(your_table_name[year])

var count_previous_special = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[quality]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[ID] = current_id
        && your_table_name[year] < current_year
        && your_table_name[quality] = "special"
        && your_table_name[city] = "NY"
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    MIN(your_table_name[city]) = "NY" && MIN(your_table_name[quality]) = "special",
    IF(count_previous_special >= 1, 0,1),
    0
)
```

This will also return 0 or 1 for year 2019 as shown below. But you can add additional filter to the IF condition if you wants 0/1 for year 2020 only.

Output-

[image]

Try this below code to compare 2020 to 2019 only-

```
new_special_2 = 

var current_id = MIN(your_table_name[ID])
var current_year = MIN(your_table_name[year])

var count_previous_special = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[quality]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[ID] = current_id
            && your_table_name[year] < current_year
            && your_table_name[quality] = "special"
            && your_table_name[city] = "NY"
            && your_table_name[year] = 2019
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    MIN(your_table_name[city]) = "NY" 
        && MIN(your_table_name[quality]) = "special"
        && MIN(your_table_name[year]) = 2020,
    IF(
        count_previous_special >= 1, 
        0,
        1
    ),
    0
)
```

Comment: may I ask, if I want to specifically compare 2020 to 2019, how shall I do that? as I may have more rows, 2018, 2017, and that way, I can compare e.g. 2020 and 2018, 2019 and 2017 etc. Many thanks!

Comment: Possible... just need to specify the requirement first.

Comment: Please check my updated answer with new code below.

Comment: Many thanks for your time! appreciate your help with this!

Comment: @Almond you can put an up vote as well :)